# Close Window with JS

Tags: javascript

So I have been trying to create a div that allows you to click on it and it'll close the tab. normally, I would accomplish this by placing onClick=" javascript:window.close();" within the HTML code and done. for this website, it doesn't seem to work. I have to place the code on the back end to stick but whenever I switch to frontend view, it's gone.

here is the code that works on the backend but not the front:

```
<a id="close-window" onclick="javascript:window.close('','_parent','');">Close Window</a>
```

the front end looks like the

```
<a id="close-window">Close Window</a>
```

I think it's cause the system has code somewhere that prevents custom Js from firing.
I tried placing e.preventDefault but I feel like I'm not using it correctly here is the [link](https://www.bouncehouserentalcompany.com/bounce-house-notes/) & code:

```
$(() => {

  $("a[href='#close-window']").on('click', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var openedWindow;

        function openWindow() {
          openedWindow = window.open('https://www.bouncehouserentalcompany.com/bounce-house-notes/');
        }

        function closeOpenedWindow() {
          openedWindow.close();
        }

  });
```

Comment: That made sense in 1998, but these days, not so much because people value being in control far more. If this is acting as a modal, why not use an actual modal? (also, given the changes in browser security over the last decade, don't put JS in your HTML. Especially not as `javascript:` in HTML4-style `on...` handlers, add your event listeners in your JS, that you have living in its own files)

Comment: from the docs This method can only be called on windows that were opened by a script using the Window.open() method. If the window was not opened by a script, an error similar to this one appears in the console: Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script. are you opening the window in js? the code you shared looks really weirrd you made two functions in your handler and didn't use a one

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the site and you have a console error. Besides everything else in the comment above, you're missing closing brackets: `)}`. Also, you need to wrap your click event handler in some kind of DOM ready function like `$(document).ready(function(){..`. This is especially because your HTML is below the script on the DOM tree.

There is a lot going on here though and I would definitely separate logic (like load one js file with all your stuff in it) as recommended in the comment.

Also, consider XSS attacks.